# Running `fs.writeFile` with JSPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, jspm

I'm trying to use Node's `fs` through `jspm`. After having installed `fs` with `jspm install fs`, I'm trying to use the `writeFile` method. I'm getting an error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function
```

When I log `fs` to the console, I see that it only has one method.

[image]

---

**main.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';
console.log(fs);
```

---

Why is `fs` only showing one available method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readFileSync` is the only function supported. The entire module is only has that one function:

```
exports.readFileSync = function(address) {
  var output;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', address, false);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if ((status > 399 && status < 600) || status == 400) {
        throw 'File read error on ' + xhr.responseURL;
      }
      else
        output = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(null);
  return output;
}
```

From https://github.com/jspm/nodelibs-fs/blob/master/fs.js

Comment: Do you know of any jspm modules that support writing files?